# Issue with ListView adapter

Tags: android, listview, jsoup

When I comment out the code for "nameAdapter = ..." or "numAdapter = ..." and leave the other one uncommented it will display the data in the listview fine. So it is able to display both separately, however, when I leave both uncommented it will only display the data involved with numAdapter. Probably a simple mistake but I can't figure out where I went wrong.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.player);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    new Logo().execute();
    new statistics().execute();
    nameAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.id.stat_name,statName);
    numAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.id.stat_number,statNum);

}

private class statistics extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    //final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    /*String[] values = new String[]{ "Ball Control", "Crossing", "Curve",
            "Dribbling", "Finishing", "Free Kick Accuracy", "Heading Accuracy", "Long Passing",
            "Long Shots", "Marking", "Penalties", "Short Passing", "Shot Power", "Sliding Tackle",
            "Standing Tackle", "Volleys"};*/
    //String[] stats = new String[16];
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {
        Document document;
        try {
            document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            num = document.select("div#stats-base p");
            statNum.clear();
            for (Element element : num) {
                statNum.add(element.ownText());
            }
            name = document.select("div#stats-base span");
            statName.clear();
            for (Element element : name) {
                statName.add(element.ownText());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        lv.setAdapter(nameAdapter);
        lv.setAdapter(numAdapter);
    }
}
```

player.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/playerPic"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/playerPic"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="104dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

simple_list_item_1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView android:id="@+id/stat_name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/stat_number"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_below="@id/stat_name"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think there's no mistery in that behavior. The last adapter you set to `lv` is the one that survives.

Comment: how can I have stat_name and stat_num be set in the same listview then?

Comment: Added an answer for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's no mystery in that behavior. The last adapter you set to `lv` is the one that survives.

If what you're looking for is to add both `statName` and `statNum`, I'd set one of them and afterwards use `.addAll(...)` on the other. For instance:

```
lv = lv.setAdapter(nameAdapter);
lv.addAll(statNum);
nameAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Don't forget the last line to let your `ListView` render the new data.